# Clustering with constraints on group composition and size

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering, constraint

Let's say that I know that in my data I have underlying clusters (if it helps, it may be reasonable to assume that I might even know how many) that are of a fixed size (let's say 4) and each cluster always contains certain elements (let's say one orange circle, a green circle, an orange triangle and one green triangle = all combinations of two factor levels). However, the variables on which I cluster have measurement error (and that can sometimes be pretty extreme) so that maybe I sometimes cannot identify one or two of the 4 members of the cluster (so, while undesirable, when we just cannot figure out how, it could also be okay to form a cluster of 2 or 3 - or perhaps 5 or 6 units - i.e. I kind of want to penalize it, but allow it).

The data might look like the plot below (but realistically the clusters are probably not that clean).

[image]

When I looked for clustering with constraints, people seem to mostly have looked about constraints of which units must or must not be clustered together, but I did not really see the kind of contraints I describe.

Are there clustering algorithms (ideally even with good software implementations in either python or R) that cover these scenarios? Or at least do / aim to do some of these things (then I could always search hyperparameters that achieve the various constraints)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with contrained clustering, but this might provide a good start: https://rdrr.io/cran/scclust/man/sc_clustering.html. There might exist related work in geospatial analysis as well.

Comment: My SPSS macro hierarchical clustering `!hieclu` has some way to constrain on both composition ans size. Thought you may not want to use SPSS, you might want to read the documentation at least. Go to my web-page and get the "Clustering" collection. Constraint on pre-composition amounts actually to doing hie. clu. within the subsamples first and then resuming the agglomeration to combine the clusters produced at that first stage.